# Closing angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker on date click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap drop-down component to show [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker) calendar on click. I works mostly fine, but the calendar block only closes on click away, it doesn't when you click on the calendar.

How can I make the calendar block close `onclick` of calendar's date, without using jQuery?

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zx0R0ODu9KosWbDb92g0?p=preview)**
[GIF](http://g.recordit.co/XSfLpxRa1B.gif)

```
<div uib-dropdown>
  <h4>
    <a uib-dropdown-toggle href="">Select Date <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
  </h4>
  <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'month', minView:'month' }"></datetimepicker>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery. You can use `$scope.$watch` and `angular.element` to automatically close is:

```
  $scope.$watch('date',function(newValue){
    newElement=angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('.uib-dropdown'))
    if(!newValue) return
    angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')).removeClass('open')
  })
```

See this Plnkr for example of use: https://plnkr.co/edit/tJr7XO5dJUrIWshyfKX6?p=preview

**Just a note:** It is better to use tag id, instead of class name (if you have multi dropdown's).

Removing and adding the `open` class it's equivalent to click the dropdown arrow (and showing and hiding the calendar)

Comment: I noticed a small issue with your solution. After you select a date, calendar block opens only on a second click. Do you know how can I prevent that?

Comment: problem in aria-expanded